# How to draw Canvas on top of HTML forms/tags?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, canvas

I'm trying to keep some `html` in the "background" that is not visible, and draw a `canvas image` to cover the whole page, but the opposite happens, the screen goes white and only shows `html` forms. `myImage` does not display.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <title>myApp</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id = "canvas">
        Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
    </canvas>


    <script type"text/javascript">
    var c  = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx  = c.getContext("2d");

    c.width  = window.screen.width;
    c.height = window.screen.height;

    var myImage = new Image();
    myImage.src ='/myImage.jpg';

    ctx.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, c.width, c.height);

    //This part seems to "overwrite" anything else I do on canvas
    document.write(

            '<div style=\"position:relative;width:800px;height:800px\">'+
            '<canvas width=\"800\" height=\"800\"></canvas>'+
            '<form id ="divForm" name=\"myForm\" action=\"http://www.example.com/form.php\" method=\"POST\" target=\"_blank\">'+
            '<input type=\"text\"   name = "id" value=\"'         + String(id)          + '\">'+
            '<input type=\"text\"   name = "username" value=\"' + String(username)  + '\">'+
            '<input type=\"text\"   name = "password" value=\"'        + String(password)         + '\">'+
            '</form>'+
            '</div>'

        );
    </script>
</body>
```

Code is kind of sloppy due to cutting pieces out to give you the idea, but it works perfectly until I add the `document.write()` which covers the `canvas`.

How can I use `canvas` to overlap the `html tags`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myImage` is not defined at `js` at Question.

`<canvas>` element does not have `width` or `height` set at `html`

```
<canvas id = "canvas">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
```

resulting in setting `c.width`, `c.height` to default `canvas` `width`, `height` at

```
ctx.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, c.width, c.height);
```

You can set `<canvas>` `width` to `window.innerWidth`, `height` to `window.innerHeight`

```
c.width = window.innerWidth;
c.height = window.innerHeight;
```

before calling

```
ctx.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, c.width, c.height);
```

---

As @Rayon pointed out, using `document.write()` could be causing issue as well. Try substituting `.insertAdjacentHTML()` for `document.write()`

```
<canvas id = "canvas">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>


<script type"text/javascript">
var c  = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx  = c.getContext("2d");

c.width  = window.screen.width;
c.height = window.screen.height;

var myImage = new Image();
myImage.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, c.width, c.height);

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",

        '<div style=\"position:relative;width:800px;height:800px\">'+
        '<canvas width=\"800\" height=\"800\"></canvas>'+
        '<form id ="divForm" name=\"myForm\" action=\"http://www.example.com/form.php\" method=\"POST\" target=\"_blank\">'+
        '<input type=\"text\"   name = "id" value=\"'         + String(id)          + '\">'+
        '<input type=\"text\"   name = "username" value=\"' + String(username)  + '\">'+
        '<input type=\"text\"   name = "password" value=\"'        + String(password)         + '\">'+
        '</form>'+
        '</div>'

    );
}
myImage.src ='http://lorempixel.com/300/300/';
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hu39u2ow/1

Comment: @Rayon `myImage` is also not defined

Comment: Thank you for your response, as I mentioned the code I posted is a bit sloppy snippets of my application I'm developing (I don't want to give too much information away). I do have the dimensions of the canvas defined, although I will update it in my provided code

Comment: Defined myImage too for your enjoyment :)

Comment: `.insertAdjacentHTML()` works! Although the submitting cleaned the canvas and opened a new page, but solved that using the `<iframe>` tag!  It works beautifully :') thank you!

Comment: @tery.blargh See updated post. Corrected misspelled `.inssertAdjacentHTML`, substituted `"beforeend"` for `"afterend"`

Answer (score 1):

A `canvas` object when initialized is fully transparent (transparent black to be precise) so it's see-through.

If you want to use it to hide elements behind it you need to set a color:

```
ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF"; // pure opaque white
ctx.fill(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Moreover when drawing an image on a canvas you need to be sure that the image actually loaded. Setting `src` and immediately drawing it is not going to work (when you set `src` of an image object an **asynchronous** load is started).

You need something like:

```
myImage.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0);
};
myImage.src = "/myImage.jpg";
```

Finally `document.write` is really not the way to go, you should instead just add the canvas on top later with:

```
var canv = document.createElement("canvas");
canv.style.position = "absolute";
canv.style.left = "0px";
canv.style.top = "0px";
canv.style.width = "100vw";
canv.style.height = "100vh";
```

Comment: I added    ctx.save();
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF"; // pure opaque white
  ctx.fill(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  ctx.restore();
It didn't make a difference. Also, I did mention the drawing onto the canvas works perfectly fine until I put document.write(); which seems to cause the canvas element to be completely ignored.

Comment: That is a very useful function, I will be using it! Thank you. But it didn't change anything at all. Again, the image is drawn perfectly until the `document.write()` function is called